# Golang net.LookupIP not working when compiled with GOARCH=amd64?

Tags: go, networking, x86-64

here is a simple program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    nameserver, _ := net.LookupNS("mylab.local")
    for _, ns := range nameserver {
        addrs, errIP := net.LookupIP(ns.Host)
        if errIP == nil {
            fmt.Printf("%s\n",addrs[0].String())
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", errIP.Error())
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the ouput compiled with GOARCH=amd64:

```
$ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o test test.go
$ ./test
?
```

The output compiled with GOARCH=386:

```
$ GOOS=linux GOARCH=386 go build -o test test.go
$ ./test                                                                                                                                                                                                  
192.168.56.3
```

I'm working on a "Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS".

Is there something obvious I missed ?

Thank you

**Update 1:** I updated the code in order to print the errIP

The output compiled GOARCH=amd64:

```
$ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o test test.go
$ ./test                                                                                                                                                                                                  
lookup dc01.mylab.local.: no such host
$ ping -c1 dc01.mylab.local
PING dc01.mylab.local (192.168.56.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from dc01.mylab.local (192.168.56.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.561 ms
```

**Update 2:** @hobbs
Here is the output with the environment var:

```
$ export GODEBUG=netdns=1
$ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o test test.go
$./test                                                                                                                                                                                                  
go package net: dynamic selection of DNS resolver
&{dc01.mylab.local.}
lookup dc01.mylab.local.: no such host
```

**Update 3:** Ok solved, thank you hobbs. I found that with arch 386, the resolver used was go. So after that I had a look at the documentation of the net package. I compiled as follow:

```
$ export GODEBUG=netdns=go
$ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o test test.go
$ ./test                                                                                                                                                                                                  
192.168.56.3
```

Comment: What are the errors? They might help explain things.

Comment: Yeah, `errIP` probably has some relevant info.  Change `fmt.Printf("%s\n", "?")` to `fmt.Printf("%s\n", errIP.Error())`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Code updated. Still don't understand why it does not work with arch amd64.

Comment: Probably it's using the native Go resolver in one case, and libc getaddrinfo in the other. Try running with `GODEBUG=netdns=1` in the environment.

Comment: Thank you hobbs. Is it possible to set the resolver ?

Comment: @hobbs Why do they give different results?